# reconnect-forever on JMS endpoint doesn't work with xa-transactions

Tags: jboss, jms, mule

I am using Mule 3.2.1 standalone and JBoss 5.1. Here's my flow:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"       xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jbossts="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts" xmlns:management="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management" version="CE-3.2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms     http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management/current/mule-management.xsd ">
<jbossts:transaction-manager/> 
<jms:connector name="JMS" specification="1.1"  numberOfConsumers="1" jndiInitialFactory="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" jndiProviderUrl="jnp://localhost:1099" connectionFactoryJndiName="java:/XAConnectionFactory" maxRedelivery="10" doc:name="JMS">
        <reconnect-forever frequency="5000"/>
</jms:connector>
<flow name="flow" doc:name="flow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="test1" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="qt1">
        <xa-transaction action="BEGIN_OR_JOIN" />
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="test2" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="qt2">
        <xa-transaction action="ALWAYS_JOIN"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

When I run it in mule and turn off jboss, and then turn it on again, my app does not reconnect to jms. In fact, it does not even try! If I remove transactions from my flow (as below), everything is fine.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"  xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"  xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jbossts="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts" xmlns:management="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management" version="CE-3.2.1"  xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/current/mule-jms.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jbossts/current/mule-jbossts.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management/current/mule-management.xsd ">
<jms:connector name="JMS" specification="1.1"  numberOfConsumers="1" jndiInitialFactory="org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory" jndiProviderUrl="jnp://localhost:1099" connectionFactoryJndiName="java:/XAConnectionFactory" maxRedelivery="10" doc:name="JMS">
        <reconnect-forever frequency="5000"/>
</jms:connector>
<flow name="flow" doc:name="flow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="test1" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="qt1">
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="test2" connector-ref="JMS" doc:name="qt2">
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Here are log fragments for these two scenarios:
[With transactions](http://pastebin.com/cifU9SHj) and 
[Without transactions](http://pastebin.com/wJmHnL8Y). I stopped mule after waiting for two minutes for reconnection.

My question is: what should I do to have `reconnect-forever` work properly with transactions?

Comment: The XA-transacted Mule infrastructure is quite different from the rest, there may be dragons in it. Do you really need XA transactions? It seems `jms:transaction` would do fine in your case.

Comment: Yes, I need XA transactions. I posted simple scenario here, but in my project I use multiple jms connectors in one transaction.

Comment: Got it. The problem feels like a bug IMO, I would file a JIRA if I was you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with both Jboss and ActiveMQ. 
It seems that the problem was resolved in issue http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6028.
I checked it and it seems that reconnect works well with version 3.3.0-RC3.